# iOS UITabbar is not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have drag and drop one `UITabBar` into my `UIViewController` (xib) and i created object like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabbar;
```

I have added `UITabBarDelegate` and my code for `didSelectViewController` is:

```
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"Selected INDEX OF TAB-BAR ==> %i", tabBarController.selectedIndex);

    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 3) {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"APICON" message:@"test" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

But when i click on `UITabBar` item alert is not coming, why?

Comment: i set that in interface builder by dragging line to fileownser

Comment: you are missing delegates... add delegates for tab bar...

Comment: added but its not that issue

Answer (score 0):

Set delegate for you tabbar from your `xib` or programatically as like follows

```
tabbar.delegate=self;
```

And replace `IBOutlet UITabBar *tabbar` into `IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabbar`

Answer (score 0):

I would drag a UITabBarController into your xib, this will be your main view controller.

You will need to create an outlet for the UITabBarController in your app delegate and in your xib connect that outlet to the tab bar controller.

After that, you can add additional tabs for your app.

You can also create an Xcode project that is a tabbed application and look at its code for additional help.

Comment: my current home page is UIViewcontroller and I added UITabBar into that .n